# How can the ketone in a β-ketoester be protected during hydride reduction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, protecting-groups

[image: Reaction scheme]

I am supposed to find what **X** is. I know that $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ will convert all carbonyl groups to alcohols, and the ester group is being reduced. The only way of ending up with a ketone that I can think of is by a pinacol reaction.

However, the answer given was that **X** was $\ce{HOCH2CH2OH + H+}$. How does this work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protecting_group Read the introduction paragraph, it is exactly the same as your question.

Comment: That was helpful.

Comment: By the way, you could technically use any alcohol you wanted to protect the ketone, although ethylene glycol is probably a reliable choice since you get the stability of a 5-membered ring. Basically, the answer isn't unique.